# same Python Script to scrape several facebook pages

Tags: python, excel, facebook, web-scraping

I found a Python script pretty useful to scrape social media content from a Facebook page (mainly publication / date / like count etc). But for my company I am in charge of getting info from 1500 pages (our hotels around the world). I have an Excel file with page_ID and URL of all the hotels, and below you'll find a part of the script I use:

```
import urllib2
import json
import datetime
import csv
import time

#app_id = "<FILL IN>"
#app_secret = "<FILL IN>" # DO NOT SHARE WITH ANYONE!
page_id = raw_input("Please Paste Public Page Name:")

#access_token = app_id + "|" + app_secret

access_token = raw_input("Please Paste Your Access Token:")
```

My question is: How can I make the script run one by one every URL without tape it manually (`app_id` and `app_secret` would stay the same, but only `page_id` would be updated)?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Change it to read from the file instead of input. But for that you need to know Python so maybe start with learning Python

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will try that.
Do you have some key word (like "Loop" "import file" "execfile" ?) I could use to orientated my research ? or may be a piece of code I could try ?  How do you call this action to read from the file ? i am keen to learn Python, but instead starting from scratch I would focus my learning on doing that first.

Thank you for your help.